# HTML file name changes the styles

Tags: html, css

I have never seen this before and it makes absolutely no sense, so I figured I would ask on here if anyone has ever come across the same type of thing.  I'm building a website using HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript, and the Bootstrap framework.  Every page is the same as far as the navbar and jumbotron at the top of each page.  I was having a weird issue where the home page, index.html, showed larger text in the navbar and a larger sized jumbotron image than all of the other pages.  It made no sense since the code and styles were the same for every page.  I copied all of the code from index.html and pasted it into test.html.  The only change was the file name, yet when I viewed test.html in the browser, it looked different from index.html.  I'm at a loss here, even when I deleted index.html and renamed test.html to index.html, the same issue happens to the new index.html.  I have simply renamed index.html to home.html to fix the problem, but has anyone else ever encountered an issue like this?

Comment: probably the best idea is to make a codepen or jsfiddle so that others can help you and find the problem. It is hard to say what the problem is now

Comment: Maybe you have some PHP or other output before HTML start?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Please provide [mcve] of your code and the problem you are facing.

Comment: Just to make sure, you've tried `CTRL + 0` (or `CMD+0`) for resetting the zoom-state of your webpage, right?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, I didn't want to include the code because I feel I would have to upload the entire site to demonstrate the issue.  There is no PHP before the HTML so that is ruled out, and yes I have tried the CTRL + 0 and the problem persists.  It is fixed by simply changing the file name, it's just a bizarre incident  that I've never come across before and wanted to see if anyone else had.